# Sheet music using MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm working on a project to automatically transcribe piano music (monophonic). I thought of creating a MATLAB GUI which could display the sheet music of the transcribed music. However I'm not quite sure how I could design the Grand Staff on MATLAB GUI. This is my first time using the GUI and would really love some help. 
I came across this link, and would like something similar to this, only thing is I'll be loading a .wav file instead of manually giving a melody.
http://www.pgea.unb.br/~mylene/PSMM/DSPFIRST/chapters/9specta/demos/musicgui/index.htm

I'm using MATLAB R2011a software.
Thanx in advance :)

[This is called the grand staff](http://susanparadis.files.wordpress.com/2008/10/grandstaff-for-dimes.jpg)

Im currently focused on only displaying the treble clef (the top 5 lines) with the clef of course.

Comment: please specify "Grand Staff"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### My first squibble

I made a stub for a music GUI, shown below.

Outcome so far:

[image: Grand staff]

The approach I took is the following:

1. Go on the web and find (royalty free) SVG images for the treble clef, bass clef, and brace.
2. MATLAB unfortunately does not support vector graphics. So, convert these SVGs to reasonably high-res PNGs.
3. Re-scale and position these images in a MATLAB figure.

In included my stub below, which shows the overall strategy I would take. Basically, I would use the same approach for all notes, rests, sharps, etc., symbols that are *fixed*. Find/create an image for the symbol, load it in MATLAB, and scale/display it where and when it's needed.

You'll have to be a bit creative, of course. For example, you don't need an image of a 128<sup>th</sup>-rest; just copy the 8<sup>th</sup> rest 3 times, and offset each copy a bit. Another example: split the image of a single 8<sup>th</sup> note up in its head and tail. Its head is equal to the quarter note, and its tail is only drawn after the last note on the same chord has been drawn.

For drawing *non-fixed symbols* (think slurs, lines connecting groups of ≤ 8<sup>th</sup> notes, etc.), you'll have to make a decision:

1. Draw them manually. You'll have to be creative with `line`, `patch`, etc., all the built-in plotting functions. Possibly quite time consuming.
2. Use images, and get creative with `imtransform` and friends. The upside is that the outcomes will probably look nicer and that it will probably consume less time. Cons are that these are part of the image processing toolbox, which not all your users may have access to.
3. Really the best: detect whether the user has the image processing toolbox (use `ver('images')`). If yes, use option 2. If no, use option 1.

### Another option

Another option altogether is to use a specialized music font. Music fonts map characters to music symbols. Good fonts are vectorizable, meaning, they can be scaled arbitrarily large or small without loss of quality. This takes away the need for many of those images. All you have to worry about is mapping the correct character to the desired symbol, and placement of the character.

But, for things like chords and the non-fixed symbols, you'll still have to use images.

### The Stub

But for now, here is the stub I used:

```
classdef SheetMusicGui < handle

    properties (Access = private)
        f  % Figure handle
        h  % Axes handle

        % Coordinates of the box
        topLineY    = 0.8;
        bottomLineY = 0.2;

        leftLineX   = 0.1;
        maxX        = 3;
    end

    methods

        function obj = SheetMusicGui(varargin)

            % Initialize figure and axis
            obj.f = figure; clf, hold on
            set(obj.f,...
                'position', [400 400 900 300]);

            obj.h = gca;
            set(obj.h, ...
                'box', 'on',...
                'xtick',[], 'xticklabel',[],...
                'ytick',[], 'yticklabel',[]);

            % Draw the grande staff
            obj.drawGrandeStaff(obj.h);

            % Make sure all measurements work out
            axis([0 3 0 1]);
        end

    end

    methods (Access = private)

        %% The Basics

        function [h] = drawGrandeStaff(obj, h)

            % First bar line
            line([obj.leftLineX obj.leftLineX], [obj.bottomLineY obj.topLineY], 'color', 'k');

            % Brace
            img = imread('brace.png');

            X = size(img,2);    xExtent = 0.068;
            Y = size(img,1);    yExtent = xExtent/X*Y;

            C = imagesc([0.01 0.01+xExtent],[0.8 0.8-yExtent],img, 'parent',obj.h);
            uistack(C, 'bottom'); % At the bottom prevents transparency issues


            % Treble staff
            line(...
                repmat([obj.leftLineX; obj.maxX],1,5), ...
                repmat(linspace(obj.topLineY, obj.topLineY-0.15, 5), 2,1), 'color','k')
            % Treble clef
            obj.drawTrebleClef(obj.leftLineX+0.04, obj.topLineY+0.05);


            % Bass staff
            line(...
                repmat([obj.leftLineX; obj.maxX],1,5),...
                repmat(linspace(obj.bottomLineY, obj.bottomLineY+0.15, 5), 2,1), 'color','k')

            % Bass clef
            obj.drawBassClef(obj.leftLineX+0.04, obj.bottomLineY+0.155);

        end

        % Draw a G clef at location X,Y
        function C = drawTrebleClef(obj, x, y)
            persistent img
            if isempty(img)
                img = imread('GClef.png'); end

            % Scale image
            X = size(img,2);    xExtent = 0.1;
            Y = size(img,1);    yExtent = xExtent/X*Y;

            % Plage image
            C = imagesc([x x+xExtent],[y y-yExtent],img, 'parent',obj.h);
            uistack(C, 'bottom'); % At the bottom prevents transparency issues

        end

        % Draw an F clef at location X,Y
        function C = drawBassClef(obj, x, y)
            persistent img
            if isempty(img)
                img = imread('FClef.png'); end

            % Scale image
            X = size(img,2);    xExtent = 0.12;
            Y = size(img,1);    yExtent = xExtent/X*Y;

            % Plage image
            C = imagesc([x x+xExtent],[y y-yExtent],img, 'parent',obj.h);
            uistack(C, 'bottom'); % At the bottom prevents transparency issues

        end

        function T = drawTime(obj, varargin)

            % TODO

            % NOTE: you had best use some pre-defined times, like common time,
            % 2/2, 3/4, 6/8, etc. It looks much nicer. Only use text() when a
            % non-common time is encountered.
        end

        function K = drawKey(obj, varargin)
            % TODO
            % NOTE: use sharp/flat below
        end

        %% Sharps, flats

        function T = drawSharp(obj, varargin)
            % TODO
        end

        function T = drawDoubleSharp(obj, varargin)
            % TODO
        end

        function T = drawFlat(obj, varargin)
            % TODO
        end

        function T = drawDoubleFlat(obj, varargin)
            % TODO
        end

        function T = drawNatural(obj, varargin)
            % TODO
        end

        %% Bars

        function B = drawBar(obj, varargin)
            % TODO
        end

        function R = drawBeginRepeat(obj, varargin)
            % TODO
        end

        function R = drawEndRepeat(obj, varargin)
            % TODO
        end

        %% Pedalling

        function P = drawBeginPedal(obj, varargin)
            % TODO
        end

        function P = drawEndPedal(obj, varargin)
            % TODO
        end

        %% Slurs & lines

        function S = drawSlur(obj, varargin)
            % TODO
            % NOTE: You'll have to do this one by hand
        end

        function P = drawGlissando(obj, varargin)
            % TODO
        end

        %% Multi-measure rest

        function R = drawMultiMeasureRest(obj, varargin)
            % TODO
        end


        %% Whole note/rest

        function N = drawWholeNote(obj, pitch, varargin)

            % TODO

            % Possibly transform note
            N = obj.transformNote(N, varargin{:});
        end

        function R = drawWholeRest(obj, varargin)

            % TODO

            % Possibly transform rest
            N = obj.transformNote(N, varargin{:});
        end


        %% Half note/rest

        function N = drawHalfNote(obj, varargin)

            % TODO

            % Possibly transform note
            N = obj.transformNote(N, varargin{:});
        end

        function R = drawHalfRest(obj, varargin)

            % TODO

            % Possibly transform rest
            N = obj.transformNote(N, varargin{:});
        end


        %% Quarter note/rest

        function N = drawQuarterNote(obj, varargin)

            % TODO

            % Possibly transform note
            N = obj.transformNote(N, varargin{:});
        end

        function R = drawQuarterRest(obj, varargin)

            % TODO

            % Possibly transform rest
            N = obj.transformNote(N, varargin{:});
        end

        %% 8th, 16th, 32nd, 64th, ...

        function N = drawSingleShortNote(obj, type, varargin)

            % TODO

            % NOTE: all short notes have a different number of tails. Just store
            % the tail as a separate figure, and copy however many times needed.
            % Use the quarter note for the head.

            % Possibly transform rest
            N = obj.transformNote(N, varargin{:});
        end

        function R = drawShortRest(obj, type, varargin)

            % TODO

            % NOTE: all short rests are just copies of the eighth rest, so you can
            % juse load one image and copy the desired number of times.

            % Possibly transform rest
            N = obj.transformNote(N, varargin{:});
        end


        function N = drawShortNoteGroup(obj, types, varargin)

            % TODO

            % NOTE: Use the quarter note for all the heads. Draw however many
            % lines (with "line" command) where needed. Top line should be
            % "fatter"; you can do this by adjusting the "linewidth" property

            % Possibly transform one or more members of the group
            N = obj.transformNote(N, varargin{:});
        end


        %% Note/Rest transformations
        % (dots, accents, inversion, decoration, etc.)

        function N = transformNote(obj, N, varargin)

            parameters = varargin(1:2:end);
            values     = varargin(2:2:end);

            if mod(nargin,2)~=0 || ...
                    ~all(cellfun('isclass', parameters), 'char') || ...
                    ~all(cellfun('isclass', values), 'char')
                error('transformNotes:no_pv_pairs',...
                    'Transforming notes is done by all-text parameter/value pairs.'); 
            end

            if numel(parameters)==0
                return; end

            for ii = 1:numel(parameters)

                parameter = lower(parameters{ii});
                value     = lower(values{ii});

                switch parameter

                    % Note may be flipped
                    case 'orientation'
                        switch value
                            case {'upright' 'normal'}
                                % No action 
                            case {'flip', 'flipped', 'upside down'} 
                                N = flipdim(N,1);
                            otherwise
                                % error
                        end

                    % Duration of note may be extended 
                    case {'extend' 'extension'}
                        switch value
                            case {'single' 'dot'}
                            case {'double' 'dotdot' 'dot dot' 'ddot'}
                            case {'triple' 'dotdotdot' 'dot dot dot' 'dddot'}
                            otherwise
                                % error
                        end


                    % Note may be accented
                    case {'accent' 'accented'}
                        switch value
                            case 'portato'
                            case 'staccato'
                            case 'staccatissimo'
                            case 'legato'
                            case 'marcato'
                            case 'marcatissimo'
                            case 'tenuto'
                            otherwise
                                % error
                        end


                    % Note may be decorated
                    case {'decoration' 'decorated'}
                        switch value
                            case {'thril' 'thriller'}
                            case {'pralthril' 'pralthriller' 'praller'}
                            case 'mordent'
                            case 'arpeggio'
                            case 'gruppetto'
                            case 'glissando'
                            case 'portamento'
                            case 'schleifer'
                            case {'grace note' 'appoggiatura'}
                            case {'striped grace note' 'acciaccatura'}
                            otherwise
                                % error
                        end

                    otherwise
                        warning('transformNotes:unsupported_parameter',...
                            'Unknown parameter: ''%s''. Ignoring...', parameter);
                end
            end

        end % transformNote

    end % Private methods

end % Class definition
```

And, just so you can run it as-is, save these images as `GClef.png`, `FClef.png` and `brace.png` in the same directory as the class definition:

[image]

[image]

[image]